# Angular Project to support both HTTP and HTTPS Request

Tags: angular, http, ssl, https, mixed-content

Can we configure our Angular 8 project to support both Http and Https request at the same time without forcefully converting http to https?

My project is giving **"Mixed Content Blocked"**, for which I added:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests"  charset="utf-8">
```

but this is converting my http request to https which my request doesn't support.